# Get current slug RouteName in Laravel

Tags: laravel, sidebar, multi-level

I want to change side bar menu to make it open and active when it requested. Here is my code:

```
 <li class="nav-item has-treeview {{Request::is('backend/*') ? 'menu-open':''}}">
    <a href="#" class="nav-link {{(request()->segment(1) == 'backend') ? 'active':''}}">
        {{$menu->name}}
        @if(count($menu->children) > 0)
        <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
        @endif
        </a>
        <ul class="nav nav-treeview @if($menu->parent_id === 0 && count($menu->children) > 0 ) dropdown @endif">
            <li class="nav-item has-treeview {{Request::is('backend*') ? 'menu-open':''}}">
                @foreach($menu->children as $menu)
                <a href="{{ url('backend/'.$menu->slug) }}" class="nav-link {{request()->is('backend/library-setting*') ? 'active':''}}">
                    {{$menu->name}}
                    @if (count($menu->children) > 0)
                    <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
                    @endif
                </a>
                @if(count($menu->children) > 0)
                <ul class="@if($menu->parent_id !== 0 && (count($menu->children) > 0)) nav nav-treeview show @endif dropdown" aria-labelledby="dropdownBtn">
                     @foreach($menu->children as $menu)
                    <li class="nav-item has-treeview">
                        <a href="{{ url('backend/'.$menu->slug) }}" class="nav-link {{ Request::is('backend/'.$menu->slug) ? ' active':''}}">
                            {{$menu->name}}
                            @if(count($menu->children) > 0)
                            <i class="fas fa-angle-left right"></i>
                            @endif
                            </a>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
                @endif
                @endforeach
            </li>

        </ul>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is, You have not mentioned `Request::is('backend/*')` inside the `@if`. If you put it inside the `@if` statement. It will work. Try like below,

```
<li @if(Request::is('backend/*')) class="active" @endif>
    <a href="{{ url('/backend/*')}}">Blog</a>
</li>
```